# Flag-count in the 10k mod-tools doesn't update

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, 10k-tools

When working with the 10k moderator tools, the "to handle by you"-flag count on the sidebar at the right should be decreased after handling flags. At least, that's what it did before the update the rolled out the new close reasons (i noticed the style also changed a bit).

Before, I would handle let's say five "not an answer"-flags. If I'd reload the site, the handled questions would be gone and the count (given that no new flags arrived) had decreased.

Now, after handling flags and reloading, the questions are still gone, but the count isn't decreased.

Also, when I handled all flags in a certain category, it's link should be gone from the sidebar. Instead, I get the link, the old count and when I click it, there are no questions on the page.

[image]

Comment: Caching. [Jarrod says as much](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187957/140890) in his answer to my bugreport.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hehe, talk about board-search... I'll mark it as a dupe.