# Posts flagged for attention but there are none

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

The comment with the Flagged Posts that seems to be new as of today states there are posts with flags awaiting my attention but the counter shows zero and when I go into flagged posts there is nothing waiting for me.[image]

Comment: Careful, the SO moderators might come at you with a stick for complaining that your flag queue is *empty*.

Comment: The dupe has been fixed, but the number can still be cached for a while.

Comment: This was reported on several per-site metas: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/flag-alert-for-no-flags http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/646/what-does-we-have-posts-flagged-for-moderator-attention-perhaps-you-can-help http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/577/why-do-i-get-a-yellow-0-flag-alert-on-the-top-bar

Comment: Not sure that that's a duplicate. I'm seeing "0" on [android.se] _and_ its meta site. I'm also seeing "1" on [webapps.se].

Comment: @MadScientist I'm seeing it on the main and meta sites for [money.SE] as well.

Comment: Seems like the issue is localized to Beta Sites and anyone with over 2k rep for mod tools.

Comment: Also observed by me and [at least one other person](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10442385#10442385) on [security.se] (there was one 10k flag, I acted on it, and (after a few minutes) the indicator changed to 0).

Comment: @Gilles I take it this issue is different from the possible duplication linked to above?

Comment: I'm seeing it on Space Exploration, with 1K reputation, which is in private beta.

Comment: @JohnBensin That prior issue had been fixed, and didn't exactly have the same symptoms anyway. So it's a new bug that happens to have somewhat similar symptoms to an older bug.

Comment: @Gilles That's what I thought, but I wanted to clarify before I raised the issue on the meta site of another beta.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey: Not limited to beta sites.

Comment: Its been tagged as 10k tools when its happening for other rep levels..

Comment: Must... make... notifications... go.... away!

Comment: This is a regression of my [marked-as-completed bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187216). I've [poked the developer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187216/flag-indicator-present-on-meta-but-no-flags-visible#comment587178_187957) about the issue.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey In private beta, 1k gets you the 10k tools :)

Comment: @Undo Ohhh I see. Cheers :)

Comment: I reopened, as it was a different bug than the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Different bug, just the exact same symptoms. :-P

Comment: Further info: I saw an indicator showing 1 flag on Hermeneutics an hour or so ago, there actually *was* a flag, and now I still see the "1" but there is no flag.  (I'm not a mod so I couldn't resolve the flag, but I added my own flag and vote to what was already there.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People were (rightfully) complaining that the [/tools/flagged indicator was a bit random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189529/3), so I decided to always show it.

Perhaps I should have checked for a count > 0 first, though.

Fixed.

Comment: So you're the Dev spending a week on the mod tools.

Comment: [Shhhhhhh](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bx6Bf.jpg) :)

Comment: I'm experiencing this now on Mi Yodeya. I have a yellow-splatted 1 on my toolbar, but there's nothing there when I click through.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, ditto.

Comment: @JarrodDixon This issue still seems to be happening on some sites it seems.

Comment: Yeah, it's due to us caching the count globally for all users.  Fixing it requires either 1) running another query on each page load for each 10K user (not acceptable) or 2) an elaborate caching scheme for each 10K user (ain't nobody got time for that :)

Comment: So, we're going to look at just removing that number by routing the /tools/flagged page's contents into different /review queues, e.g. low quality flags -> Low Quality Posts review queue. Discussing it now internally.