# My own flag appears in my flag queue but I can't see it

Tags: bug, review, flags

I just flagged an answer as 'not an answer' and it immediately appeared in the flag queue which in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189856/posts-flagged-for-attention-but-there-are-none) from yesterday I believed to have been removed. When I go into my queue the flag does not show but it shows the flag on the right hand side but no where else. When I click on the link to the flag the page refreshes but nothing else happens.[image]

Comment: It is *related* to the question that Vigbyor linked, a consequence of the way that Jarrod reworked the flag indicator system. But it is not a duplicate. Guess we need to add more `if` statements...