# Flagged posts indicator continues to show a flag count even though I've handled the flag

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools

I've noticed for some time now on Meta Stack Overflow that flags I've handled still continue to show up in the [Moderator Tools (10k tools) - Flagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) page.

There was a "not an answer" flag on MSO, which I flagged again as per the instructions, and although the queue is clear, the page still continues to show 1 active flag. Even if I leave the page and come back, it still shows an active flag.

Here's a screenshot of the page showing 1 flag, despite nothing showing in the list.

[image]

---

This may be happening on other sites as well, where 2k/10k users participate in looking at flagged posts.

Comment: Well, yeah, the flag hasn't been handled by mods, so... mm...

Comment: BTW, is not only on meta.se but AU suffers this as well

Comment: @Braiam - It's a new phenomenon. I've been handling flags for a long time, and in the past they've disappeared as soon as I cast my own flag, even when moderators hadn't marked the flag as helpful/declined yet...

Comment: well that's the behavior I've seen for... almost a month (time I got my first 10k in AU) and when I looked around nobody was complaining.

Comment: @Braiam - I don't think it's the end of the world, but it's just something I wanted to document. Thanks for confirming it happens on more than one site. The only other site I have 10k on is Stack Overflow, but there are just so many flags there that it would be hard for me to confirm this.

Comment: How did you get the 10k flag indicator to show back up in the top bar?

Comment: Good eye, @UndotheSnowman, I hacked it back in by reworking Michael Mrozek's soflags userscript. You can get it from here as either a Chrome Extension or a userscript: https://github.com/jamesmortensen/se-flags. Also, there's a feature request to get that added back into all sites by default: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153298/can-we-give-10k-and-2k-beta-users-the-moderator-experience-by-reducing-the-vis

Comment: This has been reported in [The flag counter in the 10k tools should reflect the posts I can actually see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196775/) and [in Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/). To quote Shog9: "we do have a long-term (6-8 weeks) plan to fix this; it's not as easy as it sounds."

Comment: ... or so they said twelve weeks ago.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I just realized [six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) is a thing.